# generics - C# - No implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, generics

I know the problem but I couldn't find solution. How can I create such a structure. What is the correct way?

```
public class BuildingListPageViewModel : ListPageViewModel<BuildingItemViewModel>
{
}

public interface ItemViewModel<T> where T:IEntity
{
    T Model { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ListPageViewModel<TVm> : PageViewModel where TVm : ItemViewModel<IEntity>
{
}


public class BuildingItemViewModel : ItemViewModel<Building>
{
}

public partial class Building : IEntity
{
    public int Id;
}
```

It gives `BuildingItemViewModel` cannot be used as type parameter `TVm` in the generic type or method `ListPageViewModel<TVm>`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `BuildingItemViewModel` to `ItemViewModel<IEntity>` error.

Comment: Hmm, code works for me. The only problem is that `BuildingItemViewModel ` doesn't implement `ItemViewModel` (there is missing property: `Building Model { get; set; }`.

Comment: @pwas No that worn't. You probably have something else.

Comment: Ok, right. Spelling mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need second generic parameter on `ListPageViewModel`:

```
public abstract class ListPageViewModel<TVm, TModel>
    where TVm : ItemViewModel<TModel>
    where TModel : IEntity
{
}
```

Then you declare classes that derive from `ListPageViewModel` with both the `TVm` and `TModel` specified:

```
public class BuildingListPageViewModel
    : ListPageViewModel<BuildingItemViewModel, Building>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ItemViewModel` needs to be [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). Otherwise, `ItemViewModel<Building>` won't be a subtype of `ItemViewModel<IEntity>`.

To make it covariant, you need to declare the type parameter as an `out` parameter and remove the setter from ItemViewModel:

```
public interface ItemViewModel<out T> where T:IEntity
{
    T Model { get; }
}

public class BuildingItemViewModel : ItemViewModel<Building>
{
    Building b;

    private BuildingItemViewModel(Building b) { this.b = b; }

    public Building Model { get { return b; } }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If I misunderstood something, I'd appreciate a comment.

Comment: Wrong. Cannot make `out` on `T`, because the property type must be input-safe. Invalid variance.

Comment: @pwas: Are you sure? T is only used covariantly in ItemViewModel, since the property has no setter...

Comment: Yes, when only `get` is specified that's true. But in the OP's code `set` is specified. Passing only once via constructor is not a replacement.

Comment: @pwas: Apparently, the OP wants a subtype relationship between `ItemViewModel<Building>` and `ItemViewModel<IEntity>`, and that's just the way to do it. Since, usually, a ViewModel is created for a single data item (which is not changed afterwards), this might just fit the OP's purpose. People often put setters in classes where all they really need is a one-time initialization...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is caused because you have created your `BuildingItemViewModel` as `ItemViewModel<Building>`. The problem is, that you want to accept `ItemViewModel<IEntity>`, where IEntity is an interface, but your BuildingViewModel is defined with a concrete type `Building`, instead of the interface, thus violating the structure and giving you an error.